# Connector Manifest not Validating in DataStudio

Tags: looker-studio

I am trying to test a connector I am building. I have created the manifest file (appsscript.json) and am trying to add this by Deployment ID to DataStudio. I keep getting an error that states:

> The connector manifest could not be retrieved or is invalid. Check the connector and try again.

Here is a a copy/paste of my appsscripts.json file:

```
{
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "dependencies": {
    "libraries": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "OAuth2",
        "libraryId": "1B7FSrk5Zi6L1rSxxTDgDEUsPzlukDsi4KGuTMorsTQHhGBzBkMun4iDF",
        "version": "24"
      }
    ]
  },
  "dataStudio": {
    "name": "VALID NAME",
    "company": "VALID NAME",
    "logoUrl": "VALID LOGO",
    "addonUrl": "VALID URL",
    "supportUrl": "VALID URL",
    "description": "VALID DESCRIPTION"
    }
}
```

I would expect this to enable the workflow of enabling the connector and then allowing the OAuth flow to be tested.

Instead, I get this error:

> The connector manifest could not be retrieved or is invalid. Check the connector and try again.

Can anyone advise why this is validating? I have followed these steps:

https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/use

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `dataStudio` part of manifest with the one is the example? Do you get the same error?

Comment: I will try that this week and let you know.

Comment: @webmasterjunkie Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 6):

Double check the permissions of your script. Especially if you are using corporate account (not from your @gmail.com address) the default sharing is corporate-only, therefore your script (and the manifest) is not available from outside.

Comment: Do you know how/where to change the default for a corporate account?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. I don't understand though why the script powering the Community Connector has to be shared to anyone with the link if we've deployed from manifest - this isn't the case with deploy as web app, the enclosing script can still be private. Is there any danger of a user potentially accessing the script behind the scenes in this case?

Comment: EDIT: nevermind, I see they talk about it here and suggest using PropertiesService for any sensitive keys, etc. https://developers.google.com/datastudio/connector/share

Comment: To be clear I found this in the sharing settings of the Google Apps Script project. I changed the link to Anyone and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Before Selecting the link, you need to select the Install add-on. It worked for me. I have enclosed the screenshot for reference [image]

Comment: How do you do this with the new UI?

Answer (score 1):

Check the installation URL if you are signed into **multiple** google accounts.

You may have to change to the u/0 section to u/1, or whichever number appears here for the relevant google account:

https://datastudio.google.com/**u/0**/datasources/create?connectorId=...